# What OpenGL version to use in LWJGL?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

Thanks to the LWJGL (LightWeight Java Game Library), I have access to plenty of static OpenGL classes. However, one think I don't understand is why should I use a specific version. In [the LWJGL 3 wiki](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.2.-OpenGL), they say:

> The static classes GL11, GL12, GL13, GL20, GL21, GL22,... can be used the access functions of a certain GL Version where GL11 would correspond to OpenGL 1.1, and GL20 would correspond to OpenGL 2.0

I understand that each class is a different version of OpenGL, but I often see many tutorials that depending on what they're doing will use a different class, switching between GL11, GL13 etc. in the same function. Wouldn't it be safer to use the same class everywhere for consistency sake? And why stay with GL11, when GL41 is available? Couldn't it be faster, since it's a more recent version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LWJGL wiki appears to be out of date. It states that:

> Note, only functions which were added in a specific OpenGL version are in a GLXX class (eg. functions in OpenGL 1.2 which were in OpenGL 1.1 are in GL11, **not GL12**)

Emphasis added. This was true for LWJGL 2.x. This would mean that you *have to* access a 1.1 function through `GL11`, even though as far as the OpenGL specification is for, that function would be available through version 4.6.

It's still *technically* true in LWJGL 3.x, in that each `GLXX` class only defines the functions added to that specific version. However, in LWJGL 3.x, all of the versioned classes *inherit* from the previous version. So while the 1.1 functions are still defined in the `GL11` class, they are *accessible* from any higher version.

Comment: So if the function glColor3f() was added in GL11, GL13 also has it but it just points to the GL11 function? Thanks!

Comment: @OscarSjöstedt: No, that is not what it's saying. It's saying that `GL13` *doesn't have it*. That's what "not GL12" says. OpenGL version 1.3 has that function, but it doesn't live in the `GL13` class.

Comment: But then it's contradictory to what I currently have: I can perfectly use GL11.glColor3f(), but I can also use it in GL12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21...

Comment: @OscarSjöstedt: I did some more research on it and it appears that LWJGL's Wiki is out of date. It describes the behavior of [LWJGL 2.x](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL12.html). In LWJGL 3 however, [the classes *inherit* from each other](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/package-summary.html). So `GL12` inherits from `GL11`, so you can access the 1.1 functions.